# On the nature of Information and Entropy definitions

Tags: information-theory

I was looking at the Shannon's definitions if intrinsic information and entropy (of a "message").
Honestly, I fail to intuitively grasp why Shannon defined those two in terms of the logarithm (apart from the desirable "split multiplication into sum" property of logarithms, which is indeed desirable).

Can anyone help me to shed some light on this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that Shannon was working at Bell Labs when he developed the idea of Shannon entropy : the goal of his research was to best encode information, with bits (so 0 and 1).

This is the reason of the log2: it has to do with binary encoding of a message. If numbers that can take 8 different values are transmitted on a telecommunication line, signals of length 3 bits (`log2(8) = 3`) will be needed to transmit these numbers.

Shannon entropy is the minimum number of bits you will need to encode each character of a message (for any message written in any alphabet).

Let us take an example. We have the following message to encode with bits:
`"0112003333"`.
The characters of the message are in `{0,1,2,3}`, so we would need at most `log2(4) = 2` bits to encode the characters of this message. For example, we could use the following way to encode the characters:

`0 would be coded by 00
1 would be coded by 01
2 would be coded by 10
3 would be coded by 11`

The message would then be encoded like that: `"00010110000011111111"`

However we could do better if we chose to code the most frequent characters on only one bit and the other on two bits:

`0 would be coded by 0
1 would be coded by 01
2 would be coded by 10
3 would be coded by 1`

The message would then be encoded like that: `"0010110001111"`

So the entropy of `"0112003333"` is between 1 and 2 (it is 1.85, to be more precise).